# How to convert sql server r2 database to Excel server via c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have database list on my web page (asp.net MVC) in dropdown control and a convert button. beside it. By selecting database name and click the convert button Database should be conver in Excel. :(... I am stuck on question how can I export all the SQL server database to Excel sheet. In fact need to prepare Workbook with name as Database name. and the table should convert in individual worksheet. Is this possible ? What should I can use. I tried with Interop objects. But its difficult to use and untranslatable. Please suggest me the  way. How to achieve this.

Comment: Another approach is to generate a csv file per table. The code would be a lot easier to create.

Comment: Thanks Silvermind, I will check on this. But Client expect everything should looks like as in database , i mean row columns. but this can be a way .any other suggestion ?

Comment: That's why I suggested CSV, because excel has a feature to import it ;)

Comment: Do you mean Database -> Coma separated Files Then Coma separated -> Excel by manual import ?

Comment: Yes, I mean the way you mentioned in the before-last comment.

Comment: Any code to convert from Dataset to CSV file in c#?